# Creating zfs zpool on initiated iSCSI disk on FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, synology, zfs, iscsi

I have properly connected an iSCSI target to my FreeBSD host using iscsictl. This new device shows up as da7. The disk shows up with:

```
geom disk list
```

as

```
Geom name: da7
Providers:
1. Name: da7
    Mediasize: 4294967296000 (3.9T)
    Sectorsize: 512
    Stripesize: 8192
    Stripeoffset: 0
    Mode: r0w0e0
    descr: SYNOLOGY iSCSI Storage
    lunname: SYNOLOGYiSCSI Storage:44281bed-ce3d-4a9f-b95e-c89b6c74c345
    lunid: 600140544281beddce3dd4a9fdb95edc
    ident: 44281bed-ce3d-4a9f-b95e-c89b6c74c345
    rotationrate: unknown
    fwsectors: 63
    fwheads: 255
```

I wanted to create a new ZFS zpool on this single disk with the command:

```
zpool create backuppool /dev/da7
```

The zpool command will now utilise a lot of cpu, but newer finishs. (Let it run for 2h).

If I create an ufs filesystem on the properly partitioned disk, the process is extremly fast. Also if I create a pool on a different raw disks, zpool finishs within seconds.

After some research I could not find any information if creating a zpool on a iSCSI target is allowed or not. Does anyone get this working?

Tested on: FreeBSD 11.1-RELEASE-p4 #0: Tue Nov 14 06:12:40 UTC 2017

Comment: It should work just fine.  Do you see any warnings in the kernel log on the initiator side?  Do you see anything suspicious in logs on the NAS?  When you run "zpool create", what do "iostat 1" and "gstat" (on the initiator side) show?

Comment: Can you read and/or write to or from the device directly using something like `dd`?